# Cache manifest doesn't work in safari but works in chrome

Tags: html, safari, browser-cache

For an html5 game I'm making at a company we've hit a snag. In safari it doesn't even seem to be trying to load our manifest file while in chrome it is. And it runs offline too. Is there any huge differences between how the two handle it that trip it up?

I'll check how firefox handles it and update in a bit. This is literally how the cache looks. Already had it validated and everything.

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#v 1.01

CACHE:
/graphics/Apalia_Map 02.jpg
/graphics/comic/PAGE4.jpg
/graphics/comic/PAGE2.jpg
/graphics/comic/PAGE8.jpg
/graphics/comic/PAGE7.jpg
/graphics/comic/PAGE3.jpg
/graphics/comic/PAGE6.jpg
/graphics/comic/PAGE5.jpg
/graphics/comic/PAGE1.jpg
/graphics/gameComplete.jpg
/graphics/ui/main_menu_bg.jpg
/graphics/ui/apaliaCredits.jpg
/graphics/levels/elpala3-lvl1.jpg
/graphics/levels/elpala1-lvl1.jpg
/graphics/levels/elpala2-lvl1.jpg
/graphics/effects/fswipe_northwest_1_4.png
/graphics/effects/spinfx08.png
/graphics/effects/shieldfx_7.png
/graphics/effects/spinfx01.png
etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer about this question.....
Safari is more funny than chrome, I can easily make chrome cache my page, but safari does not.
I list these key to make the instruction clearly for the dump like me:

1. The HTML tag contain Manifest file name like this:

< !DOCTYPE html>

< html manifest="safari.manifest" >

1. addType, I use apache server, my http.conf contain this in IfModule which contain those addtype:

< IfModule >

....(other content...)

AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest

< /IfModule >

1. The manifest file name is "safari.manifest". Its content is the most funny part, I have a html that only contain the javascript. I have no image so I don't have anything in NETWORK and FALLBACK. So I don't even fill them in the safari.manifest.

My failed safari.manifest content is:

CACHE MANIFEST

So it does not work.

My success safari.manifest content is:

CACHE MANIFEST

NETWORK:

FALLBACK:

SO FUNNY that I STILL need that "NETWORK FALLBACK" empty blocks in the file to make safari cache the page. If I don't add that two words, Safari will not cache anything.

That's all I found.

Answer (score 0):

not sure as I can't ***see*** what is happening, but the problem could be related either to the way you link to the manifest file or (and I'll place my bets now) to the mime-type the file gets sent with ([**has** to be "text/cache-manifest"](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#writing-cache-manifests)).